# Limit of an integral (coming from random walks and networks) as $n\to\infty$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, physics, network-flow

I have the following integral on hand $$I_n=\int_{0}^\infty\frac1x\left[1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)^{-n}\right]\ \mathrm dx$$

I am trying to find out what $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n$ evaluates to.

I have a sneaking suspicion that the limit is infinite (which comes from a heuristic argument based on the fact that a uniform random walk on $\mathbb Z^2$ is recurrent), but I am not sure if this particular integral would diverge.

My heuristics is as follows. I model my lattice $\mathbb Z^2$ as a resistance network $G$, and then look at square sublattices $G_n$ centered at the origin. Then $G=\lim_{n\to\infty} G_n$. Let us look at a unit current flow, such that the voltage at the origin is $V$ and at the boundary is $0$. Then the probability of a random walk starting at the origin 'escaping' to the boundary of $G_n$ before returning to the origin is (by a standard theorem in electric networks) given by $$\mathbb P_0=\frac{r(0)}{R^{(n)}_{eff}}$$

where $r(0)$ is the resistance at $0$ (here it is $1/4$) and $R^{(n)}_{eff}$ is the effective resistance between $0$ and the boundary of $G_n$. Since the random walk in $\mathbb Z^2$ is recurrent, this probability must go to $0$, and thus the effective resistance must diverge (That the effective resistance diverges is shown by the fact that $R_{eff}^{(n)}\ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\to \infty$, which is another method of showing the random walk is recurrent).

If we now just try to evaluate the effective resistance between any 2 points $G$ physically, it quickly becomes a mess. [Here's](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm) a nice walkthrough of how one goes about doing this. A more thorough mathematical treatment is in *Probability on Trees and Networks* by *Russel Lyon* and *Yuval Peres*, section 4.3. Also see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/401210). The takeaway is that the effective resistance between the origin and any point $(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^2$ is given by

$$R_{m,n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x=0}^\infty\frac1x\left[1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{m+n}\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)^{m-n}\right]\ \mathrm dx$$

(see equation 14 in the walkthrough). I am looking at this integral with $m=0$, and the constant factors stripped way to get my $I_n$. Since the effective resistance should diverge however I look (this is probably not precise, but that is why I am calling this a heuristic), I am expecting this integral to diverge, but I am not sure to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{x-i}{x+i}$ is unit.

Comment: @Bob Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @BobDobbs What do you mean by 'is unit'? I am very sorry that I don't understand. As Inori says, can you elaborate?

Comment: On the unit circle...

Comment: @BobDobbs Yes that makes sense, but how does that help?

Comment: Something potentially relevant- for the closed-form of $I_n$ for a given $n$, the coefficient of $\pi$ in that answer follows this [sequence](http://oeis.org/A089165). I'm unsure about the constant though. To demonstrate: $I_1=\pi,\, I_2=4\pi-8,\, I_3=17\pi-48,\, I_4=80\pi-\frac{736}{3},\, I_5=401\pi-\frac{3760}{3},\,\dots$. Mathematica seems to suggest $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=\infty$.

Comment: The asymptotic of the integral can be described numerically by $I(n)≈3.234+2\ln n$, where the second term can be obtained by means of heuristic consideration.

Comment: @Svyatoslav That is extremely intriguing. How did you get to this conclusion?

Comment: I evaluated to constant term analytically:  $a=3\ln2+2\gamma = 3.23387287148...$. Please see below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The integral is real and by means of the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ can be presented in the form
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x}\bigg(1-(-1)^n\Big(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan x)\bigg)$$
The integral converges for both even and odd $n$; for the convenience we will consider the first case (even $n$):
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x}\bigg(1-\Big(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan x)\bigg)\tag{1}$$
Splitting the interval of integration $[0;1];[1;\infty)$ and making the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ in the second part, also using $\cos(2n\arctan \frac{1}{t})=\cos(2n\arctan t)$ for even $n$,
$$I(n)=2\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}\bigg(1-\Big(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan t)\bigg)\tag{2}$$
Making the substitution $\displaystyle x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$
$$I(n)=2\int_0^1\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\Big)\Big(1-x^n\cos(2n\arctan\frac{1-x}{1+x})\Big)dx=I_1+I_2\tag{3}$$
where
$$I_2=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\Big(1-x^n\cos(2n\arctan\frac{1-x}{1+x})\Big)dx=2\ln 2+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\tag{4}$$
because
$$\Big|\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}\cos(2n\arctan\frac{1-x}{1+x})dx\Big|<\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}dx=O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$$
To evaluate $I_1$, we present it in the form ($H_n$ denotes the n-th harmonic number)
$$I_1=2\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx+2\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}\Big(1-\cos(2n\arctan\frac{1-x}{1+x})dx\Big)$$
$$=2H_n+4\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin^2(n\arctan\frac{1-x}{1+x})dx$$
At $n\to\infty$ the second term contributes only in the narrow region near $x=1$, and with the accuracy up to vanishing terms we can write
$$I_1\sim 2H_n+4\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sin^2(n\frac{1-x}{1+x})dx$$
Making the change $t=1-x$,
$$I_1\sim 2H_n+4\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^n}{t}\sin^2\frac{nt}{2}dt\sim 2H_n+2\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-nt}}{t}\big(1-\cos (nt)\big)dt$$
Making the substitution $x=nt$, expanding integration to $\infty$ and using the Frullani integral
$$I_1\sim 2H_n+2\Re\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x+ix}}{x}dx=2H_n+2\Re\ln(1-i)=2H_n+\ln2$$
Using the asymptotic $\displaystyle H_n=\ln n+\gamma+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$
$$I_1=2\ln n+2\gamma+\ln2+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\tag{5}$$
Putting (4) and (5) in (3),
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=2\ln n+2\gamma+3\ln2+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\sim 2\ln n\,+\, 3.233872... \,\,}$$

*$\bf{Appendix}$*

Heuristic consideration - quick evaluation of the leading term.

The integral is real and by means of the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ can be presented in the form
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x}\bigg(1-(-1)^n\Big(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan x)\bigg)$$
The integral converges for both even and odd $n$; for the convenience we consider the first case (even $n$):
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x}\bigg(1-\Big(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan x)\bigg)\tag{a}$$
At $ x<\frac{1}{n}$ we choose some $\alpha<1$;
$$ I_1(n)\sim\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{n}\frac{dx}{x}\bigg(1-\Big(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\Big)^n\cos(2n\arctan x)\bigg)\sim\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{n}\frac{dx}{x}\Big(1-(1-2nx)\cos(2nx)\Big)$$
Keeping only the main term
$$I_1(n)\sim \int_0^\frac{\alpha}{n}2n\,dx=2n\frac{\alpha}{n}=2\alpha$$
We see that the main term does not depends on $n$ and has some constant value at $x\to 0$. In the similar way we can evaluate the integral at $x\to\infty\,(x\in [\beta n;\infty), \beta>1)$ and get a constant as a main term as well.

Evaluating the remaining part of the integral, we can drop the second term in (a).

At $x\in[\frac{\alpha}{n};\beta n]$
$$I_3(n)\sim\int_{\frac{\alpha}{n}}^{\beta n}\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(\alpha\beta n^2)=const+2\ln n$$
If we change $\alpha, \beta$, we get only an additional constant term; therefore, the main term is $2\ln n$, and we can conclude that
$$I(n)=a+b\ln n=a+2\ln n$$
In fact I found that $b=2$ and $a\approx3.234$ from a couple of numeric evaluations (please see the comment and evaluations by @KStarGamer; I also checked $I(n)$ for $n=30, 40, 50$)

Comment: It seems that there is any asymptotic expansion of the form $$
I(n) \sim 2\log n + 2\gamma  + 3\log 2 - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }} - \frac{{43}}{{120n^4 }} -  \ldots  \sim 2H_n  + 3\log 2 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{3}{{8n^4 }} -  \ldots 
$$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary, thank you! I could not proceed further. This is really interesting that the higher terms are $\sim\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$; one could expect that the term $\sim\frac{1}{n}$ was not zero...

Comment: I gave a derivation of the asymptotic expansion in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is an elaboration on Svyatoslav's answer using the notation given there. Note that formula $(2)$ actually holds for both even and odd values of $n$, and hence the following derivation does not depend on the parity of $n$. First, with the change of variables $x=\mathrm{e}^{-t}$, we obtain
\begin{align*} 
I_2 & = 2\log 2 - 2\int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n }}{{1 + x}}\cos \left( {2n\arctan \left( {\frac{{1 - x}}{{1 + x}}} \right)} \right){\rm d}x} 
\\ & = 2\log 2 - 2\int_0^{ + \infty } \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - nt} }}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}}\cos \left( {n\operatorname{gd}(t)}\right){\rm d}t
\\ & = 2\log 2 - 2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}}\exp \left( { - n\left( {t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right){\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
Here $\operatorname{gd}$ is the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function). The same substitution, [Frullani's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) and the [known](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2011.10.004) formula
$$
H_n  = \psi (n + 1) + \gamma  = \log n + \gamma  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}} \right){\rm e}^{ - nt} {\rm d}t} 
$$
leads to
\begin{align*}
I_1  =  2\log n + 2\gamma  + \log 2
 & + 2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - n(1 - {\rm i})t} \frac{{1 - \exp \left( { - n\left( {{\rm i}t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right)}}{t}{\rm d}t} 
\\ & - 2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t}} \right)\exp \left( { - n\left( {t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right){\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
Accordingly,
\begin{align*}
I(n) =  2\log n + 2\gamma  &+ 3\log 2
   + 2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - n(1 - {\rm i})t} \frac{{1 - \exp \left( { - n\left( {{\rm i}t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right)}}{t}{\rm d}t} 
\\ & - 2\operatorname{Re}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}} + \frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t}} \right)\exp \left( { - n\left( {t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right){\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
Looking at Svyatoslav's answer, we see that the leading order behaviour of $I(n)$ has been extracted out and the two integrals are $o(1)$ for large $n$. Now in the first integral, we make the substitution $t=s/n$ and expand the second factor (the fraction) of the integrand about $s=0$. Integrating term by term then yields
\begin{multline*}\tag{$\star$}
2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (1 - {\rm i})s} \frac{{1 - \exp \left( { - {\rm i}s + n{\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(s/n)} \right)}}{s}{\rm d}s} 
  \\ \sim - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }} - \frac{1}{{4n^4 }} - \frac{{169}}{{126n^6 }} - \frac{{1145}}{{72n^8 }} -  \ldots 
\end{multline*}
as $n\to +\infty$. For the second integral, we apply [Laplace's method](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iii):
\begin{multline*}
 - 2\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}} + \frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t}} \right)\exp \left( { - n\left( {t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)} \right)} \right){\rm d}t} 
\\  \sim \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{a_k }}{{n^{2k} }}}  =  - \frac{{13}}{{120n^4 }} - \frac{{13}}{{24n^6 }} - \frac{{19381}}{{2880n^8 }} -  \ldots 
\end{multline*}
as $n\to +\infty$, where
$$
a_k  =  - 2\operatorname{Re} \frac{{{\rm d}^{2k - 1} }}{{{\rm d}t^{2k - 1} }}\left[ {\left( {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}} + \frac{1}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t}} \right)\left( {\frac{{ t}}{{t - {\rm i}\operatorname{gd}(t)}}} \right)^{2k} } \right]_{t = 0} .
$$
Thus, in summary,
$$\boxed{
I(n) \sim 2\log n + 2\gamma  + 3\log 2 - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }} - \frac{{43}}{{120n^4 }} - \frac{{949}}{{504n^6 }} - \frac{{21727}}{{960n^8 }} -  \ldots\, }
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

*Remark.* With some work, it can be shown that the coefficient $b_k$ of $n^{-2k}$ in the expansion $(\star)$ is
$$
b_k= - \frac{2}{k!}\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (1 - {\rm i})s} s^{2k - 1} B_k\! \left( {{\rm i}\frac{{1!}}{{3!}}E_2 s, \ldots ,{\rm i}\frac{{k!}}{{(2k + 1)!}}E_{2k} s} \right){\rm d}s} 
$$
where $B_k$ denotes the [complete exponential Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials) and $E_k$ are the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers).

Comment: Gary, this is an elaborated and comprehensive solution which provides the way to most general result. The best solution. It is always fascinating to look at a professional' work.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much. I made some simplifications using the Gudermannian function + added a remark.

Comment: This solution providing a general answer is enchanting and far beyond my amateur abilities  :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Your answer provided me with plenty of inspiration to see what form I should aim for.

Comment: The result is absolutely awesome. Honestly, this is some great work. Thank you for working hard on this!